How to create a column with quantiles ranked groups in SAS using weight?
I have a dataset which has the following relavant variables, along with many others:
data have;
 input group $ score weight;
    datalines;
A 12 1.2
A 19 1
A 23 1.7
A 40 2
A 11 1
A 16 1.5
A 34 1.3
A 45 1
A 28 1.8
A 30 1.2
A 24 1.1
A 28 1
B 31 1.5
B 32 1.6
B 36 1.9
B 18 2
B 28 1.4
B 25 1.3
B 22 1.8
B 27 1.6
B 31 1.5
B 42 1.7
;
run;

I am used to do ranked groups in SAS using the proc rank statement, for example:
proc rank data=have groups=4 out=want;
  by group;
  var score;
  ranks score_quartiles;
run;

But PROC RANK does not handle weights, and for what I researched, I need to use proc univariate, transpose the results, erase duplicated ties, and merge back to the original dataset. But I am not being able to figure out how to do so.
Any help is really appreciated.

What did you try?  Since you have a BY group you cannot exactly follow the example in https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug09/ap/AP01.pdf unless you generate a different format for each BY group.

Yeah, I was trying to follow this document you quoted, but couldnt figure out how to do so.
There is no easy way for SAS to create ranked groups using weitght?

Rather than trying to generate a format why not just generate some IF/THEN logic from the output of PROC UNIVARIATE.
So first use PROC UNIVARIATE with the WEIGHT statement to generate the cutpoints you want to use for your rankings.
proc univariate data=have noprint;
  by group;
  var score;
  weight weight;
  output out=wide pctlpre=p_ pctlpts=25 to 75 by 25;
run;

proc transpose data=wide out=tall name=percentile ;
  by group;
  var p_: ;
run;

Then use those to generate IF/THEN logic to assign RANK based on GROUP and SCORE.
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set tall;
  by group;
  file code;
  if first.group then do;
    rank=0;
    put 'if ' group= :$quote. 'then do;' 
      / '  if missing(score) then rank=.; '
    ;
  end;
  rank+1;
  put '  else if score < ' col1 'then ' rank= ';' ;
  if last.group then do;
    rank+1;
    put '  else ' rank= ';' / 'end;' ;
  end;
run;

Then run the code
data want;
  set have;
%include code / source2;
run;

For your example data that leads to this data step:
833  data want;
834    set have;
835  %include code / source2;
NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) file CODE is file ...
836 +if group="A" then do;
837 +  if missing(score) then rank=.;
838 +  else if score < 19 then rank=1 ;
839 +  else if score < 28 then rank=2 ;
840 +  else if score < 34 then rank=3 ;
841 +  else rank=4 ;
842 +end;
843 +if group="B" then do;
844 +  if missing(score) then rank=.;
845 +  else if score < 25 then rank=1 ;
846 +  else if score < 31 then rank=2 ;
847 +  else if score < 32 then rank=3 ;
848 +  else rank=4 ;
849 +end;
NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) ending.
850  run;

NOTE: There were 22 observations read from the data set WORK.HAVE.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 22 observations and 4 variables.


Thanks Tom, you are the king of SAS. I didnt followed all the steps of your code, but it worked and I was able to grasp the general idea and rewrite it in a way I could understand. As the output of the first proc univariate already saved the quantiles, I could merge it back to the original dataset using IF/THEN logic to assign the quartiles to individuals

If the weights are only one or two decimal places you can create a view that replicates the weights as repeated observations.
Example:

data f10 / view=f10 ;
  set have ;
  do ix = 1 to weight * 10 ;
    output;
  end;
run ;

data f100 / view=f100 ;
  set have ;
  do ix = 1 to weight * 100 ;
    output;
  end;
run ;

proc rank data=f10 groups=4 out=want_f10 (where=(ix=1)) ;
  by group;
  var score;
  ranks score_quartiles;
run;

proc rank data=f100 groups=4 out=want_f100 (where=(ix=1)) ;
  by group;
  var score;
  ranks score_quartiles;
run;

* comparing results of weightx10 replicates versus weightx100 replicates ;
* shows the results are exactly the same;
ods listing;
proc compare noprint data=want_f10 compare=want_f100 outnoequal out=diffs;
run;

